# Why are isotopically pure diamonds 50% more thermally conductive than other diamonds?

Tags: thermodynamics, materials, conductivity, isotope, carbon-allotropes

A laboratory grown type-IIa diamond (no nitrogen defects) has a lambda of $\pu{1800-2200 W/mK}$, but an isotopically pure diamond of $\ce{^{12}C}$ can have up to $\pu{3320 W/mK}$.

Why are $\ce{^{12}C}$ diamonds so much more thermally conductive than diamonds with $\approx \pu{1.1\%}$ $\ce{^{13}C}$ atoms?

Sourcing for my question:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/092596359290197V?via%3Dihub 
https://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990PhRvB..42.1104A

Comment: Less phonon scattering from the 'impurity' C13 atoms. I'm not equipped right now to dig up the original paper, but the predicted results matched quite well with reality.

Answer (score 4):

From [*THERMAL  CONDUCTIVITY  OF  NATURAL  AND  ISOTOPICALLY  ENRICHED  DIAMOND  - EFFECT OF NEUTRON IRRADIATION, D.P. White, Department of Physics, Merrimack College, N. Andover, MA 01845*](http://web.ornl.gov/sci/physical_sciences_directorate/mst/fusionreactor/pdf/dec2001/07.3%20-%20134-138%20WHITE.pdf):

> The thermal conductivity was calculated using the Callaway method.  This method takes into account  the  effects  of  intrinsic  three-phonon  normal  (N)  processes.    These  processes  do  not create thermal resistance directly but affect the thermal resistance by transferring phonons from frequencies where they are not scattered to frequencies where scattering is more efficient.

[...]

> In order to  explain  the  large  increase  (originally  much larger  than  expected)  in  terms  of  isotope scattering it was necessary to include the effects of N processes.  Subsequent analyses of the thermal  conductivity  of  enriched  diamond  have  included  N  processes.    Wei et.al.  used  the Callaway  expression  to  fit  experimental  thermal  conductivity  data  on  diamond  with  the  natural isotope  concentration  and  isotopically  enriched  (0.1% $\ce{^{13}C}$)  diamond  over  a  wide  temperature range (100-1000K).

Comment: OK, nice reference. But what does it mean?

Comment: The TL;DR is that the thermal conductivity of diamond is dependent upon it's intrinsic scattering phonon relaxation times. This property is at a maximum (meaning maximum thermal conductivity) with maximal isotopical purity (of either 12C or 13C), and at a minimum when there is a 50% mixture. This is not linear in nature, as even a diamond with 1% of one isotope has markedly lower relaxation times than one with 0.1%. This is a difficult topic (for me) to summarize, though I should probably have given it some discussion. Honestly there's not much of a shortcut here vs reading the cited article.

Comment: Airhuff - thank you! I've only found data on conductivity of 12C diamonds and not 13C - is the lambda of a 13C diamond similar to that of a 12C diamond (~3300 W/mK)?

Comment: Also, would a boron doped 12C diamond be more conductive than a pure 12C  as it's electrically conductive? Here's another good explanation of phonon conductivity: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/17250/42303

Comment: I found then lost a link to an article in which they made pure 13C diamonds, pure 12C diamonds and many mixes in between. I'm sure I'll find it and I have some time to search now. Great answer by Dryden that you linked to. Off the top of my head, I would guess that a boron doped diamond would have increased phonon scattering, but maybe also increased electronic conductivity???

Comment: Still can't find that article, but here's one you might find interesting. Their claim (one of them anyway) is that (if I understood it correctly) that the heat conductivity of diamonds is _all_ about phonons, and the electronic element is irrelevant. [Isotopically-pure carbon-12 or carbon-13 polycrystalline diamond possessing enhanced thermal conductivity](http://www.google.com/patents/US5540904).